# Django Framework - Is there a shutdown event that can be subscribed to?

Tags: python, django, web

I have a problem which I am hoping might be solved with some form of shutdown hook in Django.

I am still a beginner with Python/Django development, and to help learn I have set myself a project of developing a COMET/Reverse Ajax style chat site that runs in browser. The browser continuously polls the server for any messages. When the server receives a poll request, it checks to see if there are any messages waiting, and if there are none, it will attempt to acquire a lock on a *threading.Lock* object which has already been acquired. This causes the thread which is handling the request to block until a message is received and the previously mentioned lock is released.

My problem arises when I shutdown the server. At this point I am using the development server (python manage.py runserver). If there is a thread blocked from the above explained process, then the server does not shutdown.

Is there a way that i can execute code when the server attempts to shutdown so that i can release any waiting threads?

I have looked at the following [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11847418/django-pre-shutdown-hook-to-close-hanging-pymongo-connection) however it hasn't helped me. There was speculation that such an event hook does not exist, however no definitive answer. I've googled high and low, but haven't had any luck.

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.5.

Grateful for any help you can provide

Comment: Not really sure how exactly this is implemented and if this will work, but I'll just put it out there - a message for shutdown that all the threads will read and understand as "Oh, I should probably stop"?

Comment: @DJV : But how would I know to send that message?

Comment: Not really sure, some sort of handle for `Ctrl+C` (a.k.a. `KeyboardInterrupt`) for the dev-server. For different servers, perhaps a different approach can be thought of. I understand that this is not a general approach and it's not done via Django, but as I said "I'm just throwing it out there".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't know of a shutdown event, but you can create one.

When the user presses Ctrl-C, a SIGINT signal is sent to Python process.  Setup a signal handler from your `wsgi.py` file to catch the SIGINT and forward it to your program.

wsgi.py:

```
...

import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, my_signal_handler)
```

You could even forward the signal to a django signal:

```
my_django_shutdown_signal = django.dispatch.Signal()

def _forward_to_django_shutdown_signal(signal, frame):
    my_django_shutdown_signal.send('system')
    sys.exit(0)   # So runserver does try to exit
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, _forward_to_django_shutdown_signal)
```

Since `signal` can only be called from the main thread, this won't work with runserver.  Either call runserver with the `--noreload` option, or switch over to gunicorn.

Comment: Any idea how to get this behavior in  Apache & mod_wsgi?

Answer (score 6):

Addition to answer by Stu Gla:
To set handler for signal event in main thread in django you can put put initialization of handling to manage.py or your app's __init__.py, like so:

```
#  {project_root}/{your_app}/__init__.py
import os  
import signal  
import sys  
def my_signal_handler(*args):  
    if os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN') == 'true':  
        print('stopped'.upper())  
    sys.exit(0) 

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, my_signal_handler)
```

It will let you run server without *--noreload*.
Check for `os.environ.get('RUN_MAIN')` pvevent calling function 2 times.