# How to handle on stop event for django?

Tags: python, django

I am new with django framework, i want to handle global events of django application like onStart and onStop of asp.net. is there anyway to do that i have handle OnStart using code below but unable to handle onStop please guide me to do that.

```
__author__ = 'qasim'

from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'api'
    verbose_name = "My Application"

    def ready(self):
        print("hello-----------------------------------------------------")
        pass  # startup code here
```

Comment: Django has absolutely nothing to do with asp.net, its unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Sayse  i want to execute code when my django server stops.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472075/django-framework-is-there-a-shutdown-event-that-can-be-subscribed-to

Comment: Well by that very definition its too late for django to do anything about it, its sounds like more a job for whatever is running your django project

Comment: @Sayse is there any way to handle this event.

Answer (score 3):

The confusion between ASP.NET and django is that the former is a server + framework and the latter is only a framework.

Django apps are executed in some server, common choices are apache mod_wsgi or uWSGI.

Depending on your server, it may be possible to run something on stop.

Comment: I also had a problem with global variables when I moved from asp.net to django. In asp.net I used to have global static variables to hold objects that had general use. I was sure that this object would be the same for all users and all requests. In django + apache mod_wsgi multiple instances of the application were started and every request ended up working with a random set of global variables in one of these instances.

Comment: What makes a global variable? If your site runs on a single server, you may use a single server process with multiple threads to handle the requests. The threads share the global variables. I don't like this approach, because: (a) it doesn't scale and (b) exposes you to synchronization issues. If the data type is not atomic, you may get the weirdest errors. If you run multiple processes, you can use shared memory. But at the same drawbacks as the globals. If you scale out to multiple servers, you have to isolate the shared state in a (volatile) storage backend anyway.

Comment: Yes I totally agree. I just mentioned this to share my experience because I thought it is similar to what OP wants to do and they are both bad ideas.