# Stopping services started in django appconfig ready() function?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If I am starting some services or threads inside ready() function of a django application.

Here are few questions that I have in same regards:

1. How to gracefully shutdown django server?
2. Similar to ready() function is there some sort of shutdown function or should I be doing such things in some other fashion or style in django ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Framework - Is there a shutdown event that can be subscribed to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15472075/django-framework-is-there-a-shutdown-event-that-can-be-subscribed-to)

Comment: Do you really need to use threads? That can be very hard to implement properly in the context of a web server. Normally you don't use threads or subprocesses to perform tasks asynchronously, you resort to a queue/workers architecture (using  Celery for example.)

Comment: Basically these threads are not for handling requests but  for subscribing consumers clients to activemq queues.